# Finding roots of equations by the half-interval method

Tags: elisp, sicp

I am now following sicp [Finding root of equations](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.3)

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(defun close-enoughp(x y)
  (< (abs (- x y)) 0.001))

(defun search(f neg-point pos-point)
  (let ((midpoint (average neg-point pos-point)))
    (if (close-enoughp neg-point pos-point)
        midpoint
      (let ((test-value (funcall f midpoint)))
        (cond ((posp test-value)
               (search f neg-point midpoint))
              ((negp test-value)
               (search f midpoint pos-point))
              (t midpoint))))))

(defun half-interval-method(f a b)
  (let ((a-value (funcall f a))
        (b-value (funcall f b)))
    (cond ((and (negp a-value) (posp b-value))
           (search f a b))
          ((and (negp b-value) (posp a-value))
           (search f b a))
          (t
           (error "Values are not of opposite sign" a b)))))

(defun negp(x)
  (< x 0))
(defun posp(x)
  (> x 0))

(defun average(a b)
              (/ (+ a b) 2))
#+end_src
```

Test it

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(half-interval-method (lambda (x) (- (* x x x) (* 2 x) 3))
                      0
                      20.0)
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
: 1.89300537109375
```

But when try to find the square root of 3

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(half-interval-method  (lambda (x) (- (* x x) 3)
                       1
                       3.0)
)
#+end_src
```

It report error:

```
progn: Wrong number of arguments: ((t) (f a b) (let ((a-value (funcall f a)) (b-value (funcall f b))) (cond ((and (negp a-value) (posp b-value)) (search f a b)) ((and (negp b-value) (posp a-value)) (search f b a)) (t (error "Values are not of opposite sign" a b))))), 1
```

What' the reason that the function so much fragile?

Answer (score 2):

You invoke the function incorrectly.
Replace

```lisp
(half-interval-method  (lambda (x) (- (* x x) 3)
                       1
                       3.0)
)
```

with

```
(half-interval-method  (lambda (x) (- (* x x) 3))
                       1
                       3.0)
```

PS. Use [`show-paren-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Matching.html) to catch such errors.